# WordPress integration set odd/even class for posts

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm using Fishpig's wordpress integration for magento.

I need to set even and odd class for posts in category list.
Category page is written by post/list.phtml - code is below.

For basic magento catalog/category in my custom theme I use this script which works nicely.

```
<script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list','none-recursive'</script>
```

**This is post/list.phtml** and *decorateList* nor *decorateGeneric* functions don't work because in front end I get `<li class="item">`

```
<?php $posts = $this->getPosts() ?>
<?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
    <div class="post-list">
        <ul id="post-list">
            <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
                <li class="item<?php if ($post->isSticky()): ?> featured is-sticky<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $post->getPostFormat() ?>">
                    <?php echo $this->getPostRenderer($post)->toHtml() ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList($('post-list'));</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.post-list li.item'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
        <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Does anyone know what could work for me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the `<script>` tag first mentioned in your post accurate, as it's missing some characters that would cause it to error - if it is.

Comment: yes, it is. Everything is completely fine in source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your class selector is correct since you your element has an id and not a class name.

```
<div class="post-list">
    <ul id="post-list">

 decorateGeneric($$('ul.post-list li.item')
```

Try changing it to

```
<div class="post-list">
    <ul id="post-list" class="post-list" >
     ....
```

To add 'odd','even','first','last' to your LI tag

```
 decorateGeneric($$('ul.post-list li'), ['odd','even','first','last'])
```

To add 'odd','even','first','last' to your UL tag

```
 decorateGeneric($$('ul.post-list'), ['odd','even','first','last'])
```

Remove all your js except (then add them one by one to see what causing the conflict

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your concern but it did't help, do you have another idea, please?

Comment: Do you have any js error in your error console?

Comment: Where do you want the odd/even on the `li` or `ul` tag. If on the `li` change it from `$$('ul.post-list')` to `$$('ul.post-list li')`. Then inspect element in chrome

Comment: I have some errors in javascript. I'll try to fix them. I want to tag only li and that change didn't work either. But what's odd to me is that the same function decorateGeneric adds tag for product list (li) in catalog.

Comment: Did you include `/js/varien/js.js` in your page header?

Comment: I have the javascript included. I checked the base template and it uses `<li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">` with productCollection function. Could it be the difference why it works in catalog but not in wordpress list? Because in source code of the catalog I can see `<li class="item last">` but in wordpress there is no last tag.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it please?

Comment: Can your provide me with a link to a live site?

Comment: I'd love to. http://bit.ly/ZtedZR

Comment: Firstly can you view page source and remove all the duplicate script tag (jquery, twitter.com/widgets.js, etc). secondly jquey should include last, below prototype) change this to `decorateGeneric($$('ol.products-list li'), ['odd','even','first','last'])`.. You seem to have some type of conflict try removing all the not magento library and add them back one by one because this link of code `Element.addClassName(elements[0], 'first');` in js.js is giving an error but when i isolated it it seem to work see http://jsfiddle.net/kdhr51w4/2/

Comment: take a look at my update

Comment: What was the exact issue?

Comment: I hope so, you proved me that the script works. The issue must be in my JavaScripter because of my untidiness.